# Why are all my labels spaced by like 4 tabs while being boderLayout WEST?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPrame and it it set to borderLayout. Then i created another JPnael which uses BoxLayout. Now i have added labels(which contain text) and textFields to the JPanel. I have also setLayout of JPanel to WEST. Now i dont know why, but I have two problems with what is being displayed.

1) The labels are all indented 4-5 tab spaces, this is so random I dont even know why it is tabbed. All the labels in this panel are like this. Please note that this only happens if I add more stuff to the JPanel. If I only have 1 label in the JPanel it is correctly alligned to the west corner of the screen. Does anyone know why they get indented when i add more elements to the JPanel?

2)The Textfields size are huge, as in they take up many lines. I have set the size of the text fields only to 20. Yet they take up like 5 lines. Why is it not just a single line?

Im sorry guys, I have been trying to fix this for the past 2 hours and dont know what is causing this issue. I would post code, but this is an assignment and I dont feel comfortable posting it on to the internet. I hope you understand.

Just to make things clear, I have a JPanel for example called "aPanel" which is set to BorderLayout then I have another JPanel called 'subPanel' which uses boxlayout and set the layout of that to be west. After this I add stuff to this 'subPanel' expecting the elements to stack over eacher other towards the left border of the JFrame.

Comment: _Just to make things clear_, please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: `I would post code, but this is an assignment and I dont feel comfortable posting it on to the internet. I hope you understand.` No I don't understand. If you want help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem so we can see exactly what you are doing. A SSSCCE will have no indication that this is an assignment, it is just code that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: first you say `Then i created another JPnael which uses BoxLayout.`, then you say `I have another JPanel called 'subPanel' which uses flowlayout`. Well, which is it BoxLayout or FlowLayout because the answer will be different.

Comment: It is boxLayout sorry.

Comment: ... and you've been given the answer so why haven't you accepted the answer?

Answer (score 3):

1) Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Fixing Alignment Problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment). When you add different components to the panel they may have different "X alignment" so you get a different layout than you expect.

2) The box layout will expand to fill the available space. So you need to override the `getMaximumSize()` method of you text fields to return the preferred height of the text field and the maxiumum width of the text field.

Edit:

Just read the last part where you mention a FlowLayout. If this is what you are using then read the FlowLayout API. It has a parameter that controls left/center/right alignment of components added to the panel.